# How does class loaders work in a WAR deployed in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I am a bit confused with how the class loading works in the below scenario. Now here's what I know about class loading.

As per the Tomcat [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). The class loading happens in the following order

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
2. WEB-INF/classes of your web application
3. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
4. System class loader classes
5. Common class loader classes --> This is tomcat's lib dir and my external jar is here

And if it is not a web-app, then the class loading happens in this order

1. Bootstrap Loader
2. System Loader
3. Application Loader

Now, in my case, I have a web application that reads some serialized data by using an external jar. When trying to read the serialized data, the jar throws `ClassNotFoundException`. But if I use my own serialization logic without using the jar, then the application works.

This is the erroneous example

```
public GenericResult getGenericResult( ){
    GenericResult cachedResult = externalJar.get( "myKey" ); // This jar uses deserialization
    return cachedResult;
}
```

This is the working example

```
public GenericResult getGenericResult( ){
    // do not mind resource closing and all as this is a just to show how I did it
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filepath);
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    GenericResult cachedResult = (GenericResult)objectIn.readObject();
    return cachedResult;
}
```

The external jar is a provided jar residing in the tomcats lib directory. What I want to clarify is that, when loading a class from this external jar, is it using the web-application based class loading as I indicated first or java class loading as I indicate second. And what could be the reason for getting a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to load from external jar. Shouldn't the `GenericResult` class be found by the class loader at `WEB-INF/Classes`??

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.result.GenericResult
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:782) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2028) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1895) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2202) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:519) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:477) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:899) ~[?:?]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1272.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1226) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2401) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2540) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2434) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2540) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2434) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:519) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:477) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream#readObject` calls [`ObjectInputStream#resolveClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#resolveClass(java.io.ObjectStreamClass)) to retrieve objects. The default implementation uses the first loader on the current thread's stack, therefore it uses the *common* loader in your case. A classloader can find only his own classes and those of its ancestors, so it can not find the classes in your web application.

If you want to deserialize an object in your web application, you need to use the web application's class loader, which is set as context class loader on the current thread. Therefore you need to extend `ObjectInputStream` like this:

```java
public class ClassloaderAwareObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

   public ClassloaderAwareObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
      super(in);
   }

   @Override
   protected Class< ? > resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      final ClassLoader tccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      final String name = desc.getName();
      try {
         return Class.forName(name, false, tccl);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         return super.resolveClass(desc);
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit:** The *Common* classloader can not load a class from your application, since it uses the usual algorithm:

1. Ask the parent (*System*) classloader,
2. Look in your own locations.

On the other hand a web application classloader uses the algorithm:

1. Ask the *Bootstrap* classloader,
2. Look in your own locations,
3. Ask the parent (*Common*) classloader.

Comment: If it is using the common loader,  then shouldn't the request get delegated to the parent loader, and eventually, it should see the class at WEB-INF/Classes right?

Comment: Yes, the _Common_ classloader first asks its parent, then looks for the class himself. However _Common_'s parent is the _System_ classloader, not one of the many web application classloaders. I edited the answer to include an explanation on how these classloaders look for classes.